# How to add image in chrome notifications from onesignal api?

Tags: php, api, google-chrome, onesignal

I'm using onesignal api to send notifications and everything works well with php+curl.

I'm now trying to attach an image to chrome users without success. It work using the onesignal backoffice but not using the api.

My options are

```
$fields = array(
    'app_id' => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    'included_segments' => array('All'),
    'headings' => $myHeadings,
    'contents' => $myContent,
    'chrome_big_picture' => 'https://..........-360x240.jpg',
    'url' => $url
);
```

What can be wrong?

Note:
The image url is ok, I tested it with the onesignal backoffice
The size of the image is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer, the good key for web usage and for chrome is chrome_web_image
Hoping that this will help someone...